# Are only types with trivial destructor suited for storage for placement new?

Tags: destructor, c++17, placement-new

The examples for placement new often use unsigned char arrays as the underlying storage. The steps can be:

1. create the unsigned char array with new
2. create an object in this storage with placement new
3. use object
4. destroy object
5. call delte for the unsigned char array to free the array

Point 5. seems only to work if we use a type for the underlying storage with a trivial destructor. Otherwise, we would call the destructor of the underlying storage type but with no object existing there. Technically, we are destructing a bunch of unsigned chars which are not present and we are lucky that the desturctor of the unsigned char type is trivial and so no-op.

What about the following code:

```
struct A{ /* some members... */ };
struct B{ /* some members... B shall be same size as A */ };

int main()
{    
    auto ptr_to_a = new A; // A object lives @ ptr_to_a    
    ptr_to_a->~A(); // A object destroyed. no object living @ ptr_to_a, but storage is preserved
    new (ptr_to_a) B; // B object living @ ptr_to_a.    
    std::launder(reinterpret_cast<b*>(ptr_to_a))->/*...*/; // use B. for this purpose we need std::launder in C++17 or we would store the pointer returned by the placement new and use it without std::launder
    std::launder(reinterpret_cast<b*>(ptr_to_a))->~B(); // B object destroyed. no object living @ ptr_to_a, but storage is preserved

    // at this point there is no object living @ ptr_to_a, but we need to hand back the occupied storage.

    // a)
    delete ptr_to_a; // undefined behavior because no object is sitting @ ptr_to_a

    // b)
    new (ptr_to_a) A; // create an object again to make behavior defined. but this seems odd.
    delete ptr_to_a;

    // c)
    // some method to just free the memory somehow without invoking destructors?

    return 0;
}
```

On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime is written:
As a special case, objects can be created in arrays of unsigned char or std::byte (in which case it is said that the array provides storage for the object) if... .

Does this imply, that its only allowed to use placement new on unsigned char and byte arrays and because they have a trivial destructor my code sample is obsolete?

Otherwise, how about my codesample? Is option b) the only valid solution?

Edit: second examlpe:

```
struct A{ /* some members... */ };
struct alignas(alignof(A)) B{ /* some members... */ };

int main()
{    
    static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B));
    A a;      
    a.~A();    
    auto b_ptr = new (&a) B; 
    b_ptr->~B();    
    return 0;
    // undefined behavior because a's destructor gets called but no A object is "alive" (assuming non trivial destructor)
    // to make it work, we need to placement new a new A into a?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you wouldn't use the storage returned by an allocation of an unrelated class `A` to put your `B` in. You don't even have to have an allocation *at all*

```
int main ()
{
    char storage[sizeof(B)];
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(B), alignof(B)>::type aligned_storage;

    auto b_ptr1 = new (&storage) B; // potentially unaligned
    auto b_ptr2 = new (&aligned_storage) B; // guaranteed safe

    // use b_ptr1, b_ptr2

    b_ptr1->~B();
    b_ptr2->~B();
    // storage ceases to exist when main returns
}
```

If you do need to dynamically allocate, I would suggest wrapping the storage in a holder struct, so that you don't end the lifetime of the thing you `new`ed.

```
struct B_holder
{
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(B), alignof(B)>::type storage;
    B * make_B() { return new(&storage) B; }
}

int main()
{
    auto holder = std::make_unique<B_holder>();
    auto * B_ptr = B_holder->make_B();

    // use B_ptr

    B_ptr->~B();
    // holder ceases to exist when main returns
}
```

Comment: Well that just dodges my question. Sure i can have my unsigned char array on the stack. Then the destructor is called when exiting the scope. Nevertheless the destructor is called which is a no operation destructor in this case, but does it have to be the case? If no, do i have to place a new object of the original type into place to prevent undefined behaviour or is it just plain not allowed to reuse storage of a class with a non trivial desturctor?

Comment: @phön Notwithstanding it's validity, I would suggest that it's just a bad idea to use an arbitrary other type for storage.

Comment: I agree that it might be a bad idea. I just use it as an example for discussion. So i made a second example avoiding the allocation. When automatic destruction begins we need a valid A object and the only way to make it work would be a placement new A, am i right? And for types with trivial destructor we dont need to do it? Because we know they have a no-op destructor? Technically, we are destroying something that is not there (when using the unsigned chars)

Answer (score 0):

For the most part yes.

You can however do something like this.

```
struct placed {
  char stuff[100];
};
struct stupid {
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(placed), alignof(placed)> data;
  ~stupid() {
    std::cout << "stupid gone\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  auto* pstupid = new stupid;
  auto* pplaced = ::new( (void*)&pstupid->data ) placed;
  pplaced->~placed();
  auto* pstupid2 = ::new( (void*)pstupid ) stupid;
  delete pstupid2;
}
```

but that is, as implied by the type name, pretty stupid.  And exceedingly hard to make exception safe without a lot of `noexcept` guarantees I didn't include above.

I am also not completely certain if `delete pstupid2` is legal, as it was created via placement new and not via a simple new expression.